# Reduce apk size in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am consuming Web Api services in my app. Though it is app with small functionality such as registration and login then also the size of the release was firstly 55 MB then i searched a bit then i got it down to 22 MB.
My settings are 
Linking- SDk assemblies only.
i have tried every other thing such as Deselect Shared Runtime.
Select Pro guard, Generate one package, all type of linking but did not get desired result. 
Am i missing something or the app size will be 22 MB.
please suggest a solution

Answer (score 8):

(Copied from : https://montemagno.com/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down)

1. **Linking Your Libraries**

> Xamarin applications use a “linker” in order to reduce your app size.
> You can browse through the documentation and find out how this works,
> but to simplify things, it uses static analysis to your app to remove
> assemblies and types that are not used in your app to bring down your
> app size. This is for any Xamarin app, so you should also try this out
> in your iOS app because it can reduce your app size in a default
> “Hello, World” application from 16MB down to 2.9MB! There are three
> settings that you can supply from the projects settings:

[image]

> **Don’t Link** will do just that, it won’t link anything and you will be left with All of Mono, mscorlib, Xamarin.Android, and a bunch of
> other stuff:

[image]

> **Link SDK assemblies only** is your safest bet and should be your default as it will only attempt to strip things out of Xamarin.Android
> and any of your third party libraries will not be touched. However, to
> really bring down your app size you should try out **Link All
> Assemblies**, as it will investigate everything and bring down your
> app size. Be sure to FULLY test your app as it is possible that the
> linker may be agressive and strip out something you need, and if that
> is the case you can actually use a **[Android.Runtime.Preserve]** flag or
> set a linkskip in your MSBuild to ensure that not all of your
> libraries get linked.
>
> So employing this practice with my Bike Now app, which uses Json.NET,
> Android Support v4, v7, Google Play Services, and Xamarin.Insights, we
> can compare and contrast the app size when we build our app to support
> all three ABIs (we will talk about this next!).
>
> - Don’t Link: 40.7MB
> - Link SDK Assemblies Only: 18.7MB
> - Link All Assemblies: 13MB
>
> As you can see linking correctly can make a huge impact, but we can do
> even better!

**2. Splitting your APKs**

> On Android, there are ABIs (Application Binary Interfaces) that you
> can support when you ship your application. The most used will be the
> armeabi-v7a, however there are still tons of devices that support and
> run the old armeabi ABI and even x86 devices as well. So to ensure
> your app is reaching the most users you most likely have come into the
> project settings and selected every single ABI (I know I do!).

[image]

> However, for every ABI that you select you are actually bundling a
> separate libmonodroid and sgen with your app. Don’t believe me then
> rename your .apk to .zip and take a look in the lib folder:

[image]

> This of course makes sense as you would need a different version of
> monodroid and sgen that supports that ABI. The issue is that you now
> have all of these libraries bundle into a single APK and your users
> will be downloading all of them! The solution for any Android
> developer (even Java devs) is to simply split up your APKs and upload
> all of them to Google Play! This way you have a smaller app size
> across all three APKs. You can do this now with a simple check in your
> project options:

[image]

> Now, instead of just a single APK to upload I have three with
> different and smaller sizes (note it will take longer to create your
> packages):
>
> - armeabi-v7a: 10.2MB
> - armeabi: 10.3MB
> - x86: 10.4MB
>
> **Notes:**
>
> You may need to close XS after selecting check box and ensure this
> flag is set in your csproj:
>
> *true*
>
> Additionally, your new APKs will be in your /bin/Release folder and
> will be marked with Signed in their file name.

**Keep your users happy and keep down that app size with these quick tips.**

Refer to these links:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process
2. https://montemagno.com/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down/
3. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/113229/what-is-the-ideal-apk-size-from-xamarin-forms-and-how-to-reduce-it-without-force-close

Comment: could you Elaborate a Little more, so that your answer stays useful even if the links went dead. Thanks

Comment: @vanilla this generates APKs for each architecture (x64, x86, arm, arm64) instead of 1 large APK

Answer (score 0):

To reduce APK file size you need to use `ProGuard` with *visual studio*. It will remove all unused code, resources and shrink `files`, `classes`, `variables` names to very short name.

How to use ProGuard you see my another stackverflow question [How to use ProgGuard with Xamarin forms.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164301/how-to-use-proguard-optimizer-tool-with-xamarin-forms)

Another option use linking Android project's properties, use **`Sdk and User assembly`** option. It some time remove code which we are actuary using so need to be careful.